# My inner div with positioning of absolute is expanding my parent div, rather than being separate

Tags: css, tailwind-css

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/tailwindcss/dist/tailwind.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="border-b flex">
   <div class="w-1/6 flex items-center justify-center p-4 border-r text-sm">
      14 hours ago
   </div>
   <div class="w-3/5 p-4 text-sm"><span>
      Dolor aliquid ipsa qui eum in voluptatem Sit non quae illo eveniet exercitation cupiditate veniam sed id animi
      </span>
   </div>
   <div class="w-1/5 flex justify-end items-center p-4 relative">
      <button class="bg-white border rounded px-1 py-1 text-xs"><i class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i></button> 
      <div class="absolute pin-b pin-r bg-white border w-32 items-center justify-center">
         <ul class="list-reset p-2">
            <li>Delete</li>
         </ul>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

As you can see from my snippet, the dropdown list expands the parent borders rather than overlay (absolute) over them, how can I get it so my dropdown (delete) will not change the parent divs, but just overlay them like the following picture:

[image]

Comment: adding position:absolute isn't enough, you need to specify top/left/right/bottom to move it from its initial place

Comment: I've tried doing that @TemaniAfif but just fully expands https://imgur.com/H0k0asv

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does that because you've set specific width for each of *border-b* child divs with classes `w-1/6`, `w-3/5` (I think it should be 4/6...), `w-1/5` (...and 1/6) so it doesn't matter that you have absolute element inside, because its parent still has specific width assigned and it will always use it.

```css
.my-list-of-actions {
  top: calc(50% + 15px); /* basicaly it's 50% + half of button height to make it appear just below */
  left: 1rem; /* same as parent's padding */
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/tailwindcss/dist/tailwind.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="border-b flex">
   <div class="w-1/6 flex items-center justify-center p-4 border-r text-sm">
      14 hours ago
   </div>
   <div class="w-4/6 p-4 text-sm"><span>
      Dolor aliquid ipsa qui eum in voluptatem Sit non quae illo eveniet exercitation cupiditate veniam sed id animi
      </span>
   </div>
   <div class="w-1/6 flex justify-start items-center p-4 relative">
      <button class="bg-white border rounded px-1 py-1 text-xs"><i class="fa fa-chevron-down">Button</i></button> 
      <div class="my-list-of-actions absolute bg-white border w-32">
      <!-- pin-b makes it stick to parent bottom and you don' want that.
      pin-r is also bad here, as it's supposed to be aligned to the left along with the button.
      Button is aligned vertically in the center so it's best to place the list just below -->
         <ul class="list-reset p-2">
            <li>Delete</li>
            <li>Edit</li>
            <li>Archive</li>
         </ul>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That's the width, though, right? It still should expand out height wise.

Comment: @TheDeepNate added code snippet and some explanation inside